# Which one to use: Java Swing or GTK+ for GNOME desktop application?

Tags: java, linux, swing, gtk

I am considering developing a GNOME desktop application with a graphical user interface. I know GTK+ is the first choice, especially when developing for the GNOME environment. End users also consider GTK+ as the first choice for applications they use. I am, however, considering future improvements: what if my application will need a port to another environments or OS like KDE or Mac or Windows? Which is the best way to go: Java Swing (because it's platform independent) or GTK+?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My users generally prefer Swing, but GTK applications are only slightly more difficult to maintain cross-platform.

> GTK doesn't run natively on Mac OS X;

GTK and its dependencies can be built using [MacPorts](http://www.macports.org/), and popular open source tools such as [Gimp](http://www.gimp.org/) and [Inkscape](http://inkscape.org/) include the required libraries in the application bundle.

> it requires to install an X server.

[X11 for Mac](http://developer.apple.com/opensource/tools/X11.html) is "fully integrated with Mac OS X."

Addendum: As @ptomato notes, the [portfile](http://trac.macports.org/browser/trunk/dports/x11/gtk2/Portfile) offers both Quartz and X11 variants.

Comment: You can also use MacPorts to install a version of GTK on OS X that doesn't need an X server at all.

Comment: @ptomato: Excellent! Can you provide a link?

Comment: there's not really any link necessary other than looking up the gtk2 port on macports.org - you will see that "no_x11" and "quartz" variants are listed (these are synonyms of each other). Just type `sudo port install gtk2 +quartz` to install that variant.

Comment: @ptomato: D'oh! I completely forgot to check the variants; link added.

Comment: My priority is gnome environment so i will go with gtk+ choice

Answer (score 5):

Use GTK+. It's available for Windows as well if you ever do want to port it, and integrates infinitely much better with gnome.

Comment: As far as I know GTK doesn't run natively on Mac OS X: it requires to install an X server.

Comment: @peoro: This is not correct; I've elaborated in another answer.

Answer (score 4):

```
UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
SwingUtilities.updateComponentTreeUI( this );
```

On *nix variants, that should produce the **GTK** PLAF in Swing.  On Apple(1) it will probably produce a theme with 'Aqua' in the name, and on Windows(1) it will be something like 'Windows'.

1) I doubt that Windows or Apple users want to see a 'GTK look' app. on their desk-top. ;)

Comment: Note that if you code in native GTK, your app will look like a native Windows app when you run it on Windows.

Comment: +1 For reference, the default L&F on Mac OS X is `com.apple.laf.AquaLookAndFeel`.

Answer (score 1):

The answer depends on what you actually want.

GTK library is native in the Gnome environment: if you want to develop an application thought for Gnome, use GTK.

If you are not so much interested in giving a native feel to the Gnome users then use whatever you want (GTK, Swing, Qt, wx ...).

---

By the way if you want my personal opinion, I prefer GTK a lot. I personally don't like Swing, especially when it tries to emulate GTK look and feel.